# Error when access to page given by heroku after a successful build of a mean stack app

Tags: node.js, heroku, mean-stack

there is a logs file that I get it

2017-12-02T08:12:09.990720+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm bugs my-app

2017-12-02T08:12:09.990867+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:

2017-12-02T08:12:09.991030+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm owner ls my-app

2017-12-02T08:12:09.991159+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

2017-12-02T08:12:10.023279+00:00 app[web.1]:

2017-12-02T08:12:10.023508+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:

2017-12-02T08:12:10.023929+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2017-12-02T08_12_09_996Z-debug.log

2017-12-02T08:12:10.096738+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2017-12-02T08:12:10.099479+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting

2017-12-02T08:12:12.801622+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`

2017-12-02T08:12:15.592323+00:00 app[web.1]:

2017-12-02T08:12:15.592371+00:00 app[web.1]: > my-app@0.0.0 start /app

2017-12-02T08:12:15.592373+00:00 app[web.1]:

2017-12-02T08:12:15.592372+00:00 app[web.1]: > ng serve

2017-12-02T08:12:15.597560+00:00 app[web.1]: sh: 1: ng: not found

2017-12-02T08:12:15.601930+00:00 app[web.1]:

2017-12-02T08:12:15.604876+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-133-generic

2017-12-02T08:12:15.605094+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! argv

"/app/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/app/.heroku/node/bin/npm" "start"

2017-12-02T08:12:15.605243+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! node v7.9.0

2017-12-02T08:12:15.605367+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! npm  v4.2.0

2017-12-02T08:12:15.605609+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

2017-12-02T08:12:15.605511+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! file sh

2017-12-02T08:12:15.605730+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno ENOENT

2017-12-02T08:12:15.605852+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! syscall spawn

2017-12-02T08:12:15.605960+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! my-app@0.0.0 start: `ng serve`

2017-12-02T08:12:15.606045+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! spawn ENOENT

2017-12-02T08:12:15.606140+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!

2017-12-02T08:12:15.606231+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the my-app@0.0.0 start script 'ng serve'.

2017-12-02T08:12:15.606317+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.

2017-12-02T08:12:15.606411+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the my-app package,

2017-12-02T08:12:15.606479+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! not with npm itself.

2017-12-02T08:12:15.606564+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:

2017-12-02T08:12:15.606648+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     ng serve

2017-12-02T08:12:15.606731+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:

2017-12-02T08:12:15.606820+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm bugs my-app

2017-12-02T08:12:15.606902+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:

2017-12-02T08:12:15.606983+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm owner ls my-app

2017-12-02T08:12:15.625719+00:00 app[web.1]:

2017-12-02T08:12:15.625890+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:

2017-12-02T08:12:15.607068+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

2017-12-02T08:12:15.626229+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2017-12-02T08_12_15_612Z-debug.log

2017-12-02T08:12:15.719237+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed

2017-12-02T08:12:15.702055+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1

2017-12-02T08:12:34.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user re@gmail.com

2017-12-02T08:12:34.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build failed -- check your build logs

2017-12-02T08:13:41.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user re@gmail.com

2017-12-02T08:13:57.303585+00:00 app[api]: Deploy b934403c by user re@gmail.com

2017-12-02T08:13:57.303585+00:00 app[api]: Release v8 created by user re@gmail.com

2017-12-02T08:13:41.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded

2017-12-02T08:13:58.043416+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting

2017-12-02T08:14:00.695597+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`

2017-12-02T08:14:02.754000+00:00 app[web.1]:

2017-12-02T08:14:02.754019+00:00 app[web.1]: > my-app@0.0.0 start /app

2017-12-02T08:14:02.754020+00:00 app[web.1]: > ng serve

2017-12-02T08:14:02.754021+00:00 app[web.1]:

2017-12-02T08:14:02.758257+00:00 app[web.1]: sh: 1: ng: not found

2017-12-02T08:14:02.760852+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! file sh

2017-12-02T08:14:02.761025+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

2017-12-02T08:14:02.761175+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno ENOENT

2017-12-02T08:14:02.761287+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! syscall spawn

2017-12-02T08:14:02.762231+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! my-app@0.0.0 start: `ng serve`

2017-12-02T08:14:02.762294+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! spawn ENOENT

2017-12-02T08:14:02.762466+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!

2017-12-02T08:14:02.762549+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the my-app@0.0.0 start script.

2017-12-02T08:14:02.762640+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

2017-12-02T08:14:02.768294+00:00 app[web.1]:

2017-12-02T08:14:02.768421+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

2017-12-02T08:14:02.768493+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2017-12-02T08_14_02_763Z-debug.log

2017-12-02T08:14:02.838392+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1

2017-12-02T08:14:02.851871+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed

2017-12-02T08:15:31.370982+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=dry-lowlands-73030.herokuapp.com

request_id=603bf5e0-1b2b-4b34-a016-b5be382f3556 fwd="105.144.187.15" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

2017-12-02T08:15:32.474243+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=dry-lowlands-73030.herokuapp.com request_id=73f09d87-c20a-476b-b7cc-f7830c97b767 fwd="105.144.187.15" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

2017-12-02T08:18:40.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user re@gmail.com

2017-12-02T08:18:40.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build failed -- check your build logs

2017-12-02T08:21:19.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user re@gmail.com

2017-12-02T08:21:33.835951+00:00 app[api]: Release v9 created by user re@gmail.com

2017-12-02T08:21:33.835951+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 4e6ea883 by user re@gmail.com

2017-12-02T08:21:34.328617+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting

2017-12-02T08:21:19.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded

2017-12-02T08:21:37.664113+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`

2017-12-02T08:21:42.152085+00:00 app[web.1]:

2017-12-02T08:21:42.152123+00:00 app[web.1]: > my-app@0.0.0 start /app

2017-12-02T08:21:42.152124+00:00 app[web.1]: > ng serve

2017-12-02T08:21:42.152124+00:00 app[web.1]:

2017-12-02T08:21:42.164295+00:00 app[web.1]: sh: 1: ng: not found

2017-12-02T08:21:42.169858+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! file sh

2017-12-02T08:21:42.170296+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

2017-12-02T08:21:42.170752+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno ENOENT

2017-12-02T08:21:42.171236+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! syscall spawn

2017-12-02T08:21:42.173965+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! my-app@0.0.0 start: `ng serve`

2017-12-02T08:21:42.174165+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! spawn ENOENT

2017-12-02T08:21:42.174630+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!

2017-12-02T08:21:42.174867+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the my-app@0.0.0 start script.

2017-12-02T08:21:42.175064+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

2017-12-02T08:21:42.185175+00:00 app[web.1]:

2017-12-02T08:21:42.185419+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in

2017-12-02T08:21:42.185565+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2017-12-02T08_21_42_176Z-debug.log

2017-12-02T08:21:42.317965+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed

2017-12-02T08:21:42.304608+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1

2017-12-02T08:23:35.486753+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=dry-lowlands-73030.herokuapp.com request_id=b3671dce-3610-47d8-abfa-357c63e329ee fwd="105.144.187.15" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

2017-12-02T08:23:36.383415+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=dry-lowlands-73030.herokuapp.com request_id=1b80ed67-ca00-411b-832c-62812a756f39 fwd="105.144.187.15" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

Answer (score 0):

Hi try these configurations in your package.json, 
Try to avoid `ng serve` for production.
Use `http-serve` instead

```
"scripts": {
    "postinstall": "ng build --no-progress -prod  --build-optimizer=false",
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "http-server ./dist/",
    "start:hmr": "ng serve --hmr",
    "start:aot": "ng serve --aot",
    "start:prod": "ng serve --prod",
    "start:prod:aot": "ng serve --prod",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "preinstall": "rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json && npm install -g http-server @angular/cli@1.5.5"
  }
```